# Network Emulator Toolkit (NEWT) ICMP failing Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, emulation, icmp

I am trying to use Microsoft's Network Emulator Toolkit to simulate poor network conditions, but it is failing to allow ICMP packets to pass through on Windows 10.

I have tried disabling the firewall, running as administrator, as well as running NEWT on another Windows 10 machine to no avail.

I'm aware NEWT is quite dated, but it works fine for me on Windows 7-8, and appears to be passing through all of the other protocols.

Could there be a specific reason NEWT on Windows 10 is rejecting ICMP packets?

NEWT: https://blog.mrpol.nl/2010/01/14/network-emulator-toolkit/